# How to re-write this code idiomatically in Scala?

Tags: scala, exception, option-type

Suppose I have a function `f: Int => String` which may throw exceptions. I would like to write a function `tryF(f: Int => String, arg: Int, defaultOpt: Option[String])`, which works as follows:

- Invoke `f(arg)` and return the result if it has thrown no exception
- if the invocation has failed with an exception and `defaultOpt.isDefined` then return `defaultOpt.get`
- Otherwise throw the exception

I am writing it as follows:

```
def tryF(f: Int => String, arg: Int, defaultOpt: Option[String]) = {
  val r = scala.util.Try(f(arg))
  r.toOption orElse defaultOpt getOrElse r.get
}
```

Does it make sense ? Would you rewrite it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A verbose, but easy-to-understand way...

```
import scala.util.{Try,Success,Falure}

def tryF(f: Int => String, arg: Int, defaultOpt: Option[String]) = {
 Try(f(arg)) match {
      case Success(r) => r
      case Failure(ex) => defaultOpt match {
           case Some(content) => content
           case None => throw ex
      } 
 }
```

Slightly more compact way:

```
import scala.util.{Try,Success,Falure}

def tryF(f: Int => String, arg: Int, defaultOpt: Option[String]) = 
 Try(f(arg)) match {
      case Success(r) => r
      case Failure(ex) => defaultOpt getOrElse {throw ex}
 }
```

Comment: I would use `defaultOpt getOrElse {throw ex}` instead of the nested pattern matching.

Comment: agreed, but outer pattern matching is still needed to get `ex`

Comment: I like the 2nd solution. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think using Try is appropriate in this instance and you would be better using try/catch as answered by Dan Getz. I would use the Try as the return type indicating success or failure.

Answer (score 5):

Your solution is fine even though I personally don't find it very readable. I would do something like that:

```
def tryF[A](f: =>A, defaultOpt: Option[A]): A = (Try(f), defaultOpt) match {
  case (Success(result), _)          => result
  case (Failure(_), Some(defValue))  => defValue
  case (Failure(t), None)            => throw t
}
```

Note that it is unnecessarily verbose (I could have used wildcard in some of the cases) but I think your use case deserves some self documenting code. It is easy to understand what triggers each case.

Comment: Thanks. The pattern matching was the alternative. It looks verbose but probably more readable (for most people at least).

Answer (score 2):

No need for `Try` in your case; `try`/`catch` is enough:

```
def tryF(f: Int => String, arg: Int, defaultOpt: Option[String]) = {
  try {
    f(arg)
  } catch {
    case e: Exception => defaultOpt getOrElse { throw e }
  }
}
```

If you want to use `Try`, I'd suggest taking advantage of [`recover`](http://scala-lang.org/api/2.11.1/index.html#scala.util.Try@recover[U%3E:T](f:PartialFunction[Throwable,U]):scala.util.Try[U]):

```
def tryF(f: Int => String, arg: Int, defaultOpt: Option[String]) = {
  Try {
    f(arg)
  }.recover({
    case _ if defaultOpt.isDefined => defaultOpt.get
  }).get
}
```

However, if this is your actual function, I'd consider rewriting the argument types to be generic, rather than rewriting the implementation, as long as the implementation already works:

```
def tryF[A, B](f: A => B, arg: A, defaultOpt: Option[B]): B = /* ... */
```

Comment: (This is not snark, at least, not intentionally) `Try { f(arg) }.recover(Function.unlift(Function.const(defaultOpt))).get` - is that really readable (as in "you can clearly see what it is doing - i.e. conditionally throwing the exception?

Comment: You're right, that was pretty unreadable. Got rid of the `Function._` stuff.

Answer (score 1):

```
def tryF(f: Int => String, arg: Int, defaultOpt: Option[String]) = {

    val r = scala.util.Try(f(arg))

    if (r.isSuccess) r.get else defaultOpt.getOrElse(r.get)

    // reads like -> if r is success, get from r, else get from default, else get from r
}
```

Comment: If `defaultOpt` is `None` I need to throw the original exception.

Answer (score 1):

```
def tryF(f: Int => String, arg: Int, defaultOpt: Option[String]) = {
  val r = scala.util.Try(f(arg))
  (r, defaultOpt) match {
    case (Success(result), _) => result
    case (Failure(_), Some(opt)) => opt
    case (Failure(ex), None) => throw ex
}
```